# Javascript: forEach function changes data

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, javascript-objects

Disclaimer: I don't know what's the proper title for this issue that I have, so any edit is welcomed.

I have an array of objects. For each object I want to change the value of one property. After I change the value with `forEach()` function the initial data is also changed, which is not what I want.
I have attached a [pen](https://jsbin.com/xayiseb/edit?js,console) so you can understand better.

Could you please have a look and explain why JS have this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: please add all relevant information to the question. please have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35922429/why-a-js-map-on-an-array-modify-the-original-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object within your array are passed by reference - meaning that whatever change they would undergo within the `forEach` function will alter 'the original'' object as well.
One example for what you can do is:
`result = Object.assign({}, element);`
Instead of `result = element;`
The `Object.assign` Will create a new copy of that object and you won't be altering your original array.

[MDN for Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

**Edit:**

In other words, JavaScript isn't creating a new object when you iterate over an array of objects. So while iterating, `element` is the the same object as in `currencyRates` array. And when assigning `result = element` result is also the same object. Both pointing to the same array, just with different names. So when your modifying `result` is like modifying `element` or alternatively modifying directly in the array - i.e. `currencyRates[0][nameOfTheDateKey] = newValue`.
When using `Object.assign` JS creates a new copy of `element` in results, and it is no longer the same object, thus manipulating it won't affect `element` and in turn won't affect your original array.
Hope it is cleared and makes more sense now.

Comment: To be honest, didn't quite understand why I get that behavior, but it worked, nevertheless. If you have more time to explain with simpler terms, it would be awesome.

Comment: @Daniel Added an extra explanation, hopefully it'll help you understand it better now

Comment: Yes, now it makes much more sense. Thank you very much!