# How to modifiy array object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two array. 1) `userDetails`, `engToGerman`

```
const userDetails= [
  {
    firstName: 'Michael Scott',
    lastName: 'Dunder Mufflin',
    designation: 'Regional Manager',
    show: 'The Office',
    responsibility: 'heart of the show'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Michael Scott',
    lastName: 'Dunder Mufflin',
    designation: 'Regional Manager',
    show: 'The Office',
    responsibility: 'heart of the show'

  },
  {
    firstName: 'Michael Scott',
    lastName: 'Mufflin',
    designation: 'Regional Manager',
    show: 'The Office',
    responsibility: 'heart of the show'

  },
]

engToGerman = [ 
   firstName: 'name',
   lastName: 'vorname'
]
```

Now I would like to modify user details like below where I translate the first name and last name from engToGerman and want to delete the rest of the information.

So the new user detail will look like this:

```
const newUserDetails= [
  {
    name: 'Michael Scott',
    vorname: 'Dunder Mufflin',
  },
  {
    name: 'Michael Scott',
    vorname: 'Dunder Mufflin',

  },
  {
    name: 'Michael Scott',
    vorname: 'Mufflin',

  }
]
```

How can I achieve this without modifying the original array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#map` to map `firstName` and `lastName`.

```js
const userDetails= [ { firstName: 'Michael Scott', lastName: 'Dunder Mufflin', designation: 'Regional Manager', show: 'The Office', responsibility: 'heart of the show' }, { firstName: 'Michael Scott', lastName: 'Dunder Mufflin', designation: 'Regional Manager', show: 'The Office', responsibility: 'heart of the show' }, { firstName: 'Michael Scott', lastName: 'Mufflin', designation: 'Regional Manager', show: 'The Office', responsibility: 'heart of the show' }, ],
    engToGerman = { firstName: 'name', lastName: 'vorname'},
    result = userDetails.map(o => ({ [engToGerman.firstName]: o.firstName, [engToGerman.lastName]: o.lastName }));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy version similar to the question / response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53966191/javascript-map-on-copied-array)

`let cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userDetails));`

Then you can do your normal array map or whatever else you need.

Comment: thank you so much. I was having difficulties to clone the array. nice solution @coolgoose

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
const newUserDetails = [];

for(let item in userDetails){ //iterate through the entire array
  const obj = {
    name : userDetails[item].firstname,
    vorname: userDetails[item].lastname
  }
  newUserDetails.push(obj);

}
```